# Rails: how do I set an attribute just by calling it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get `@user.stripe_customer_id` to return a string. If it isn't set, then it should run a call to an external service, set it, and return it.

More verbosely here are my tests:

```
context 'Stripe ID' do
  it 'should not be writable' do
    expect { @user.stripe_customer_id = 'random_id_123123' }
      .to raise_error(NoMethodError)
  end

  it 'should be generated if it does not exist' do
    @user.save
    expect(@user.stripe_customer_id).to include('cus')
  end
end
```

where `@user` is a valid `User << ActiveRecord` instance.

Rspec fails with the following:

```
Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87 # User Stripe ID should be generated if it does not exist
```

And the `User.rb` file has the following lines:

```
  def stripe_customer_id
    if stripe_customer_id.blank?
      stripe = Stripe::Customer.create(
        description: "Username: #{username}",
        email: email
      )
      self.stripe_customer_id = stripe.id
      save!
    end
    stripe_customer_id
  end

  private

  def stripe_customer_id=(new_customer_id)
    write_attribute(:stripe_customer_id, new_customer_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to overwrite the getter method for `stripe_customer_id`

```
def stripe_customer_id
  self[:stripe_customer_id] || write_attribute(:stripe_customer_id, new_customer_id)
end
```

This is an untested code which i just wrote up. But i'm pretty sure this should work for your case. Please give it a try an let me know.

Comment: Passed it! Thank you!

Comment: you had defined `stripe_customer_id=` method which is a setter method, used to set values and not get them. :)

Comment: Yes, I have the setter private to pass the first test.. which makes the attribute unwritable directly. But I called the setter in my custom setter too.. but for some reason, that didn't work.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the first two lines of your method definition `def stripe_customer_id
    if stripe_customer_id.blank?`

Comment: You are defining and calling the same method. recursive method calling. You must have ended up in a loop over there.

Comment: YES! I understand now, I wasn't using `self[:stripe_customer_id]` and instead called `self.stripe_customer_id` which ended up in a loop. Thank you!